# Toggle nested, boolean object property (at arbitrary depth) -- possible without eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

Consider this code:

```
var a = {
    b: {
        c: true
    },
    d: {
        e: false
    }
};

function toggle() {
    var prop='';
    for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        prop += '.' + arguments[i];
    }
    eval('a'+prop+"=!a"+prop);
}

toggle('b', 'c');
console.log('a.b.c : ', a.b.c);
console.log('a.d.e : ', a.d.e);
toggle('d', 'e');
console.log('a.b.c : ', a.b.c);
console.log('a.d.e : ', a.d.e);
toggle('b', 'c');
console.log('a.b.c : ', a.b.c);
console.log('a.d.e : ', a.d.e);
toggle('d', 'e');
console.log('a.b.c : ', a.b.c);
console.log('a.d.e : ', a.d.e);
```

Calling `toggle('b', 'c')` or `toggle('d', 'e')` will flip the boolean value of `a.b.c` or `a.d.e`, respectively.

Is there any downside to using `eval` here, other than `eval` being evil (which, of course, it is not :) ) ?

If so, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using array notation to access properties, instead of dot notation.

```
function toggle() {
    var obj = a;
    for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length-1; i++) {
        obj = obj[arguments[i]];
    }
    obj[arguments[i]] = !obj[arguments[i]];
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed! This is what I was looking for :)